# How to create datatable from specific row datagridview

Tags: c#, desktop-application

How Create Data Table From Top 5 or 6 row in datagridview including  column  header also .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your explanation is too short. Any how, what i understand from this is that **either** you have a datable and you want to bind its just top 5 to 6 rows to data grid **or** u want to bring your data grid  row to datatable with headers both can done through for each loop..

You can get column names like this from data

```
string columnName = mydatagrid.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
```

OR you can get both rows and column using foreach loop

```
 foreach(DataGridColumn col in dg.Columns)
   {
     dt.columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
   }

 foreach(DataGridRow in dg.Rows)
 {
  if(dt.Rows.Count < 6)
  //Add data to data table

 }
```

The same way you can apply with little modifications to get data from datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq as follow

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().Skip(5).Take(6);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question !

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't do anything with question. datatable.AsEnumerable().Skip(5).Take(7).CopyToDataTable() its return datatable that mention in this question

Comment: He needs to move gridview rows to a datatable and again you are using `Skip(5)>take(6)` whereas he hasn't asked anything on skipping rows

Comment: Yes I know, but diffidently, the gridview has Datasource and he can use the Linq expression on DataSource object.